# Arquillian + Wildfly + Gradle Warnings

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, jboss-arquillian

I've written this gradle script: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba7de8e301eef7be3f3c

When I run my test, gradle warns me about some dependencies:

> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.interceptor.GlobalInterceptorExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.interceptor.GlobalInterceptorExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.DeltaSpikeContextExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.DeltaSpikeContextExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.jmx.MBeanExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.jmx.MBeanExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.ConfigurationExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.ConfigurationExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exception.control.extension.ExceptionControlExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exception.control.extension.ExceptionControlExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.message.MessageBundleExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.message.MessageBundleExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.extension.ExcludeExtension java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.extension.ExcludeExtension
>
> WARN: JBAS016006: Could not load portable extension class org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.provider.BeanManagerProvider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.provider.BeanManagerProvider

I'm not able to figure out what's going wrong.

My Test class is:

```
package com.living.features.arquillian;  
  
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;  
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;  
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;  
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;  
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;  
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
  
import javax.inject.Inject;  
  
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;  
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;  
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;  
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.gradle.archive.importer.embedded.EmbeddedGradleImporter;  
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;  
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;  
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;  
import org.junit.Test;  
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
  
import com.living.authz.oauth.persistence.repository.exceptions.RepositorySystemException;  
import com.living.mock.ArquillianAlternative;  
import com.living.mock.MockFactory;  
import com.living.rest.dto.FollowUpActivityDTO;  
import com.living.rest.dto.metainfos.values.MetaInfoValueDTO;  
import com.living.rest.dto.metainfos.values.StringMetaInfoValue;  
import com.living.rest.services.FollowUpActivityService;  
import com.living.rest.services.ResourceService;  
  
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)  
public class ArquillianTest  
{  
  
    @Inject protected FollowUpActivityService fuaService;  
    @Inject protected ResourceService resourceService;  
      
    @Deployment  
    public static WebArchive createDeployment()  
    {      
        System.getProperties().remove("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory");  
        EmbeddedGradleImporter importer = ShrinkWrap.create(EmbeddedGradleImporter.class);  
        WebArchive war = importer.forThisProjectDirectory().importBuildOutput().as(WebArchive.class);  
          
        war.addClass(ArquillianAlternative.class);  
        war.addClass(MockFactory.class);  
          
        JavaArchive[] libs = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);  
        war.addAsLibraries(libs);  
          
        //System.out.println(war.toString(true));  
          
        return war;
    }
      
    @Test  
    public void categorize()  
    {  
        FollowUpActivityDTO receivedFuaDTO = new FollowUpActivityDTO();  
        receivedFuaDTO.setId("idFuaCategorize");  
          
        MetaInfoValueDTO receivedMetaInfoValue = new StringMetaInfoValue("key", "value");  
          
        try {  
            this.fuaService.createOrUpdate(receivedFuaDTO);  
            this.fuaService.categorize(Arrays.asList(receivedFuaDTO.getId()), Arrays.asList(receivedMetaInfoValue));  
              
            FollowUpActivityDTO categorizedFuaDto = this.fuaService.findOne(receivedFuaDTO.getId());  
            assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), hasSize(1));  
              
            assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), hasItems(  
                                                            hasProperty("key", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getKey())),  
                                                            hasProperty("value", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getValue()))  
                                                        ));  
              
        } catch (RepositorySystemException e) {  
            fail(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you export the tree view of the war you're using as your deployment please?

Comment: Take a look on [here](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/477f95e4659ce22d145b). Thanks.

Comment: I see you're deploying to an embedded container, is it the same result if it's a remote or managed container?

Answer (score 1):

The error you provided indicates that you're referencing DeltaSpike extensions in your code.  Your gradle build shows deltaspike as a test only dependency, meaning it's not in your WAR file.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba7de8e301eef7be3f3c#file-arquillian-gradle-L51

If you're actually using DeltaSpike, it should be a compile/runtime dependency.